# If $v = v_1 + v_2$ and $\lVert v\rVert \leq 1$ then $\lVert v_1\rVert \leq 1$. Why is it true? (Hilbert spaces and orthogonality)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

We have $H^1_0 \subset L^2$ where $w_j$ is an orthogonal basis on $H^1_0$ and orthonormal basis on $L^2$.

Let $v= v_1 + v_2$ with $\lVert{v}\rVert_{H^1_0} \leq 1$, where $v_1 \in \text{span}\{w_j\}$ for $j = 1,...,N$ and $v_2$ is such that $(v_2,w_j) = 0$ for $j = 1,...,N$.

Why is it true that $\lVert v_1 \rVert_{H^1_0} \leq 1$?

I don't see it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $(v,v)=\lVert v\rVert^2$ and $(v_1,v_2)=(v_2,v_1)=0$.

**Alternate Hint**: Under what conditions on $x_1,x_2$ does $$\lVert x_1+x_2\rVert\leq\lVert x_1\rVert+\lVert x_2\rVert$$ become an *equality*?

Comment: So $|v|^2 = |v_1|^2 + |v_2|^2$ hence $|v_1|^2 \leq 1-|v_2|^2$. Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all.